# Automatically formatting links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

On this answer [Comparison of different concepts of integral](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/98/comparison-of-different-concepts-of-integral/320#320) we see that the link to another me.SE question is reformatted with the title of the question. When the link was inserted I just copy-pasted it from the address bar on the browser.

But the links to the math.SE are not reformatted. Is this a bug?

I point this out because we have already seen several links to questions and answers on math.SE and it would be nice to have them reformatted as well.

So writing: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315768/how-to-create-the-set-of-hyperreal-numbers-using-ultraproduct should produce the title of that math.SE question and not the link.

Comment: This isn't a special to this site -- links to Math Overflow posts from Math Stack Exchange also do not autoformat.

Comment: @JimBelk: I sort of already knew, but I wanted to make the suggestion anyway. From what I understand one is welcome to encourage change even on the local meta's on SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, only links [from the site itself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69483/1438) are automagically converted from a URL to a link with the title of the the question.  Feel free to [support this proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59569/display-other-se-site-links-in-the-linked-questions-sidebar) which would provide better support for cross-site links.

Comment: I was kinda guessing that this was the case, but I wanted to suggest it anyway. I voted on the other proposal.